# changing cornerradius of Flex label and changing arrow of combo box

Tags: apache-flex

I have two questions.

1. How do I change the corner radius of a Label component in Flex. Tried applying style name, and the setStyle('cornerRadius',9) methods, but doesn't work.
2. How can I change the arrow image in the combo box control to a different image?

Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've edited my answer. 
Looks like the only way to do it is wrap the Label in a container like an HBox

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" horizontalAlign="right" id="hbox1" cornerRadius="16" borderStyle="solid">
  <mx:Label label="{stuff}" id="opLabel" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: Tried it...and I get the error 'Cannot resolve attribute 'cornerRadius' for component type mx.controls.Label.'

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark components use the BorderContainer control

```
<s:BorderContainer id="brdr"
                   cornerRadius="6"
                   width="80" height="30"
                   horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
                   <s:Label id="lblFoo" 
                            text="Bar"
                            width="100%" height="15"
                            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the combobox arrow you need to change the following skins:

- upSkin
- overSkin
- downSkin
- disabledSkin

For an editable combobox you need to change the following skins:

- editableUpSkin
- editableOverSkin
- editableDownSkin
- editableDisabledSkin

Answer (score 0):

If you coding on actionScript try this one, first you have to create in your css file attribute, for example:

```
CSS-File
.lineCorner{  corner-radius: 20; }
```

And in your main mxml app you have to set `styleName` to your **Label** like this example:

```
var myLabel:Label = new Label();
myLabel.text = "Bla-Bla-Bla";
myLabel.styleName = "lineCorner";
this.addChild(myLabel);
```